# Signing xadesSignedProperties gives error (Invalid signed properties hashing, SignedProperties with id=xadesSignedProperties

Tags: cryptography

Signing `xadesSignedProperties` gives error (Invalid signed properties hashing, SignedProperties with id='xadesSignedProperties')

Here is my hashed signature properties :

```
                                <ds:Reference Type="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#SignatureProperties" URI="#xadesSignedProperties">
                                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                                    <ds:DigestValue>YmZlNTJiODNjMzQwMzE5ZWQ5MDM2NzVjNTc1YmRiMzI1YzFjM2E3MzkxMWRkZmQ4YzcwMTM2YTVkMTE2NjI5NQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                                </ds:Reference>
```

These are signature properties:

```
<xades:QualifyingProperties Target="signature" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
                                <xades:SignedProperties Id="xadesSignedProperties">
    <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
        <xades:SigningTime>2023-05-28T08: 20: 58Z</xades:SigningTime>
        <xades:SigningCertificate>
            <xades:Cert>
                <xades:CertDigest>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"></ds:DigestMethod>
                    <ds:DigestValue>MTA0YzhiMzNkNjRlZmE5OWZkN2EwYjkyODBmMWI3MjllODA0OGQzODE2MTU2NmQ3MTkwMWQ5OGJmZmI4MDZkYQ==</ds:DigestValue>
                </xades:CertDigest>
                <xades:IssuerSerial>
                    <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=eInvoicing</ds:X509IssuerName>
                    <ds:X509SerialNumber>1685004381661</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                </xades:IssuerSerial>
            </xades:Cert>
        </xades:SigningCertificate>
    </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
</xades:SignedProperties>

                            </xades:QualifyingProperties>
```